# Flutter: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called when widget tree was locked... during orientation change

Tags: android, dart, flutter, drawer, flutter-layout

I want to create a App whose UI can be updated based on device orientation. In Portait layout, i use a drawer to show some elements ([Fig.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1M9hc.png)). In Landscape layout, there is no drawer but the elements are showed in a column at left of screen ([Fig.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6g4yW.png)). The program works, when the drawer is closed.

But when i **switch orientation from portait to landscape with drawer opened**, i got error of "setState() or markNeedsBuild() called when widget tree was locked"
The stack provides this info:

```
Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
I/FlutterActivityDelegate(28527): onResume setting current activity to this
I/flutter (28527): PORTRAIT LAYOUT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
I/hwaps   (28527): JNI_OnLoad
I/flutter (28527): LANDSCAPE LAYOUT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
I/flutter (28527): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (28527): The following assertion was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:
I/flutter (28527): setState() or markNeedsBuild() called when widget tree was locked.
I/flutter (28527): This _ModalScope<dynamic> widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is
I/flutter (28527): locked.
I/flutter (28527): The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was:
I/flutter (28527):   _ModalScope<dynamic>-[LabeledGlobalKey<_ModalScopeState<dynamic>>#e1f0f](state:
I/flutter (28527):   _ModalScopeState<dynamic>#830e3)
I/flutter (28527):
I/flutter (28527): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (28527): #0      Element.markNeedsBuild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3453:9)
I/flutter (28527): #1      Element.markNeedsBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3462:6)
I/flutter (28527): #2      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1141:14)
I/flutter (28527): #3      _ModalScopeState._routeSetState (package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart:464:5)
I/flutter (28527): #4      ModalRoute.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart:562:30)
I/flutter (28527): #5      ModalRoute.changedInternalState (package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart:1018:5)
I/flutter (28527): #6      _ModalRoute&TransitionRoute&LocalHistoryRoute.removeLocalHistoryEntry (package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart:348:7)
I/flutter (28527): #7      LocalHistoryEntry.remove (package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart:296:12)
I/flutter (28527): #8      DrawerControllerState.dispose (package:flutter/src/material/drawer.dart:201:20)
I/flutter (28527): #9      StatefulElement.unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3821:12)
I/flutter (28527): #10     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1697:13)
I/flutter (28527): #11     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1695:7)
I/flutter (28527): #12     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3676:14)
I/flutter (28527): #13     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1693:13)
I/flutter (28527): #14     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1695:7)
I/flutter (28527): #15     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3676:14)
I/flutter (28527): #16     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1693:13)
I/flutter (28527): #17     ListIterable.forEach (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:39:13)
I/flutter (28527): #18     _InactiveElements._unmountAll (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1706:25)
I/flutter (28527): #19     BuildOwner.finalizeTree.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2328:27)
I/flutter (28527): #20     BuildOwner.lockState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2160:15)
I/flutter (28527): #21     BuildOwner.finalizeTree (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2327:7)
I/flutter (28527): #22     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:628:18)
I/flutter (28527): #23     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:208:5)
I/flutter (28527): #24     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:990:15)
I/flutter (28527): #25     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:930:9)
I/flutter (28527): #26     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:842:5)
I/flutter (28527): #27     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:120:13)
I/flutter (28527): #28     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:109:3)
I/flutter (28527): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (28527): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 3424 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState != _ElementLifecycle.defunct': is not true.
I/flutter (28527): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 3424 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState != _ElementLifecycle.defunct': is not true.
I/flutter (28527): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 3424 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState != _ElementLifecycle.defunct': is not true.
I/flutter (28527): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 3424 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState != _ElementLifecycle.defunct': is not true.
I/flutter (28527): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 3424 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState != _ElementLifecycle.defunct': is not true.
I/flutter (28527): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 3424 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState != _ElementLifecycle.defunct': is not true.
I/flutter (28527): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 3424 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState != _ElementLifecycle.defunct': is not true.
I/flutter (28527): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 3424 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState != _ElementLifecycle.defunct': is not true.
I/flutter (28527): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 3424 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState != _ElementLifecycle.defunct': is not true.
I/flutter (28527): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 3424 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState != _ElementLifecycle.defunct': is not true.
```

And i got a go back button at leading of Appbar([Fig.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJrV2.png)).

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: new Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  static const int SCREEN_WIDTH_MIN = 600;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget _homelayout;
    var screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    var screenOrientation = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation;
    if ((screenWidth > SCREEN_WIDTH_MIN) &&
        (screenOrientation == Orientation.landscape)) {
      print('LANDSCAPE LAYOUT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!');
      //_homelayout = _buildLandscapeLayout(context);
      _homelayout = _buildLandscapeLayout();
    } else {
      print('PORTRAIT LAYOUT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!');
      _homelayout = _buildPortraitLayout();
    }
    return _homelayout;
  }

  Widget _buildPortraitLayout() {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('demo'),
      ),
      drawer: new DeviceListDrawer(),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Text('body'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget _buildLandscapeLayout() {
  return new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      title: new Text('demo'),
    ),
    body: new Center(
      child: new Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          new DeviceListDrawer(),
          new Text('body')
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class DeviceListDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DeviceListDrawerState createState() => _DeviceListDrawerState();
}

class _DeviceListDrawerState extends State<DeviceListDrawer> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      width: 200.0,
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            width: 200.0,
            color: Colors.blue,
            padding: new EdgeInsets.only(
                top: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top + 16.0, bottom: 16.0),
            child: new Text('demo '),
          ),
          new Expanded(
            child: new ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Text('item 1'),
                new Text('item 2'),
                new Text('item 3'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          new RaisedButton(
            child: new Text('add item'),
            onPressed: () {},
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Could you please point out what is the problem? And how i can make a layout dynamique? Thanks for your help.

Comment: This usually happens when you are already in the new view (in your case landscape mode) and call setState on the portrait mode which is already gone. You should programmatically close the drawer before going to landscape mode.

Comment: I agree with you Bostrot. I have tried to close the drawer with Navigator.pop() at the beginning of build method of  _HomeState and it not work. Do I have idea where should I close the drawer? thanks

Answer (score 2):

you can try

`Navigator.pop(context, true);`

instead of

`Navigator.pop()`

Answer (score 0):

```
void rebuild(BuildContext context) {
  Navigator.pop(context);
  setState(() {});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For new people that run into this, one thing you can do is simply lock the device orientation in portrait mode while the drawer is open.  This prevents that error.

In my case, I build the app bar and drawer differently depending on screen width (which obviously changes with orientation), and like the OP I only build the drawer with narrow screens (which occurs in portrait mode on smaller devices).

> ```
> return Scaffold(
>   appBar: _buildAppBar(context),
>   drawer: _buildDrawer(context),
>   body: Beamer(
>     key: _beamerKey,
>     routerDelegate: routerDelegate,
>   ),
>   onDrawerChanged: (isOpened) {
>     // this is a workaround to fix an error that happens if user changes
>     // device orientation while drawer is open.  Basically, we lock it
>     // in portrait mode when the drawer is open so it can't be rebuilt
>     // without the drawer by rotating the device.
>     if (isOpened) {
>       // lock orientation to portrait mode while drawer is open
>       SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
>           [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]);
>     } else {
>       // closed, unlock
>       // lock orientation to portrait mode while drawer is open
>       SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
>         DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
>         DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
>         DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
>         DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight
>       ]);
>     }
>   },
> );
> ```