# How to use a Pagview PageController in Flutter using Redux

Tags: redux, flutter

I am using Redux within Flutter (and I am just starting to learn both).  I have been trying to figure out how to switch between the  pages of a PageView using the PageView's PageController.

However, whenever I try to use the PageController.jumpToPage() function, I get an exception stating:

"The following assertion was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:  setState() or markNeedsBuild() called when widget tree was locked."

When I attempt to call the PageController.jumpToPage() in my reducer, it does navigate to the page within the pageview; but the exception gets thrown.

I have also tried just building a new PageController in the reducer, and just setting the PageController's initial page property to the desired page, but that didn't seem to do anything.

I have run out of ideas on how to figure this out on my own, so I thought I would ask here.  Any help would be appreciated.

I have thrown together a quick sample showing what I am trying to do:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:redux/redux.dart';
import 'package:flutter_redux/flutter_redux.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final store = Store<AppState>(appReducer,
      initialState: AppState.initial(), middleware: []);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StoreProvider(
      store: store,
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'PageView Example With Redux',
        home: MyPageViewContainer(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AppState {
  final List<Widget> pageViewList;
  final PageController pageController;

  AppState({
    this.pageViewList,
    this.pageController,
  });

  factory AppState.initial() {
    return AppState(
      pageViewList: [
        PageOne(),
        PageTwo(),
      ],
      pageController: PageController(initialPage: 0),
    );
  }

  AppState copyWith({
    List<Widget> pageViewList,
    PageController pageController,
  }) {
    return AppState(
      pageViewList: pageViewList ?? this.pageViewList,
      pageController: pageController ?? this.pageController,
    );
  }
}

AppState appReducer(AppState state, action) {   

  if (action is NavigateToPageOneAction) {
      state.pageController.jumpToPage(0);
    return state;
  }
  else if (action is NavigateToPageTwoAction) {
    state.pageController.jumpToPage(1);
    return state;
  }
  else {
    return state;
  }      
}

class NavigateToPageOneAction {}

class NavigateToPageTwoAction {}

class MyPageView extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Widget> pageViewList;
  final PageController pageController;
  final Function onPageChanged;

  MyPageView({
    this.pageViewList,
    this.pageController,
    this.onPageChanged,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PageView(
      controller: pageController,
      children: pageViewList,
      onPageChanged: onPageChanged,
    );
  }
}

class MyPageViewContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  MyPageViewContainer({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StoreConnector<AppState, _MyPageViewModel>(
      converter: (Store<AppState> store) => _MyPageViewModel.create(store),
      builder: (BuildContext context, _MyPageViewModel vm) {
        return MyPageView(
          pageViewList: vm.pageViewList,
          pageController: vm.pageController,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class _MyPageViewModel {
  final List<Widget> pageViewList;
  final PageController pageController;
  final Function onPageChanged;

  _MyPageViewModel({
    this.pageViewList,
    this.pageController,
    this.onPageChanged,
  });

  factory _MyPageViewModel.create(Store<AppState> store) {
    _onPageChanged() {}

    return _MyPageViewModel(
      pageViewList: store.state.pageViewList,
      pageController: store.state.pageController,
      onPageChanged: _onPageChanged(),
    );
  }
}

class PageOne extends StatelessWidget {
  PageOne();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Page One"),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Column(),
      drawer: MyDrawer(),
    );
  }
}

class PageTwo extends StatelessWidget {
  PageTwo();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Page Two"),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      body: Column(),
      drawer: MyDrawer(),
    );
  }
}

class MyDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  MyDrawer({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StoreConnector<AppState, _MyDrawerViewModel>(
      converter: (Store<AppState> store) => _MyDrawerViewModel.create(store),
      builder: (BuildContext context, _MyDrawerViewModel vm) {
        return Drawer(
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(vm.pageOneText),
                  onTap: vm.pageOneOnTap,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(vm.pageTwoText),
                  onTap: vm.pageTwoOnTap,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class _MyDrawerViewModel {
  final String pageOneText;
  final String pageTwoText;
  final Function pageOneOnTap;
  final Function pageTwoOnTap;

  _MyDrawerViewModel({
    this.pageOneText,
    this.pageTwoText,
    this.pageOneOnTap,
    this.pageTwoOnTap,
  });

  factory _MyDrawerViewModel.create(Store<AppState> store) {
    _goToPageOne() {

     store.dispatch(NavigateToPageOneAction());
    }

   _goToPageTwo() {

     store.dispatch(NavigateToPageTwoAction());
   }

    return _MyDrawerViewModel(
      pageOneText: "Page One",
      pageTwoText: "Page Two",
      pageOneOnTap: _goToPageOne,
      pageTwoOnTap: _goToPageTwo,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems that we are using Redux in different ways.  You may take a look at my example:  https://github.com/lhcdims/statemanagement02

Comment: @KennethLi I see that we do have different approaches, I will certainly take a look at your project in more detail to see what I can learn, I was following the pattern that I was learning from tutorials on https://flutterbyexample.com/ and others.  I have been able to navigate to individual pages using the Navigator, but I'm trying to figure out how to switch between pages within a PageView widget using its PageController. Looking at your sample, if you placed all three pages into a PageView and tried to navigate to a page within it with an OnTap event from a Drawer, how would you go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have figured out how to solve my problem.  I saw an answer in this post: [Flutter: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called when widget tree was locked... during orientation change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51090078/flutter-setstate-or-markneedsbuild-called-when-widget-tree-was-locked-du)

In that post the OP was encountering the same error when changing between portrait and landscape mode while the Drawer was open.  The answer in that post suggested calling Navigator.pop() (which closes the Drawer) before changing view modes.

So I gave that a try and closed my Drawer using the Navigator.pop() prior to using the PageController's .jumpToPage method.  This seems to work, and allows me to navigate between pages of the PageView using onTap events from the Drawer, without throwing the "The following assertion was thrown while finalizing the widget tree: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called when widget tree was locked" exception.

I assume that this means that while the Drawer is open, the widget tree is placed into a locked state.

Hopefully this helps someone, as it took me a while to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

@Blau

Sometimes an event happened outside any widgets you built.  e.g. (1) A timer that increment a 'Global Counter', this counter will be shown in many pages/widgets  (2) A message sent from the socket server, on receiving this message/event, the user may be anywhere(any pages/widgets), and you don't know where to 'setState' (Or the widget is actually not there because the user is not at that page)

I've built 2 examples that demonstrate how to use Redux to solve this kind of problems:

Example 1: (Use a multi-thread timer to 'setState' a widget when an external event fires)

https://github.com/lhcdims/statemanagement01

Example 2: (Use Redux to refresh a widget when an external event fires)

https://github.com/lhcdims/statemanagement02

Demo Screen Shot:

[image]